# manage variables in python for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

below are input date values I have:

```
job1_started = '2020-01-01' 
job1_end  = '2021-01-01' 
job2_started = '2022-01-01' 
job2_end = '2023-01-01' 
. 
. 
jobn_started = '2023-01-01' 
jobn_end = '2023-01-01'
```

below is the input list I have:

```
lst=['job1','job2',...... 'jobn']
```

I need to loop through all values in list and add 1 day to its corresponding date Values.

```
for date in lst:
    < logic needed>
```

below is the expected Output: (adding one day)

```
job1_started = '2020-01-02'
job1_end  = '2021-01-02'
job2_started = '2022-01-02'
job2_end = '2023-01-02'
. 
.  
jobn_started = '2023-01-02'
jobn_end = '2023-01-02'
```

How can I do this?

Comment: For n jobs you are creating 2*n variables. Don't do this. Instead use a list of lists `mylist = [[job1_start, job1_end], [job2_start, job2_end], [...]]` I'd recommend first refactoring your code like this before trying anything else. Then you can access jobn start like this `mylist[n][0]` and jobn end like this `mylist[n][1]`

Comment: List and dates are inputs from source. i can't change them. For whatever the job i have in the list , its  corresponding start and end date should be added by 1 day

Comment: what you posted is code where you create n*2 variables. This is not input by source, this is actual code you posted, so my recommendation is to not create all those variables, but store your inputs in a list of lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If I understand correctly, your first question is how to retrieve a variable value by its name. I show you two ways.

   - data structure `dict`

     There are two intrinsic directories recording all global/local variables from their names to values in the current scope, which can be obtained via [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) and [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) respectively. Therefore `globals()['job1_started']` or `locals()['job1_started']` will give you the value of global variable `job1_started` or the local one.
   - built-in function [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

     `eval` evaluates an expression string in the given namespace (default local namespace). Therefore, `eval('job1_started')` is equivalent to `locals()['job1_started']`. But you should be very **careful** when using `eval` because the string could be a dangerous expression, e.g., `"__import__('os').system('rm -rf something_important')"`.
2. The second question is how to add 1 day to a date string. You can achieve this with [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) module.

   - use [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert string to [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) object， and [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) for the reverse
   - use [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) to update date

**Example**

```py
import datetime

job1_started = '2020-01-01'
job1_end = '2021-01-01'
jobs = ["job1"]

for job in jobs:
    for suffix in ('_started', '_end'):
        var_name = job + suffix
        date_str = locals()[var_name]
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d") # 2020-01-01 00:00:00
        date_delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        date = date + date_delta  # 2020-01-02 00:00:00
        date_str = datetime.datetime.strftime(date, "%Y-%m-%d") # '2020-01-02'
        # update the variable at the local scope
        locals()[var_name] = date_str
        print(f'{var_name} = {date_str}')
```